# Convert Microsoft Curly Quotes to Straight Quotes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, double-quotes, smart-quotes

I am having a really hard time trying to fix a Clients Database records.  I need to Find and Replace all Curly Quotes which look like this `“` with  Straight Quotes `"`

[image]

**Attempt 1**
I have tried to run this on my MySQL database with no luck.

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'“','"');
```

**Attempt 2**
I have also tried search and replace in PHP with the below, with no luck as well

```
<?php
$str = ' “evil curly quotes“ no "good straight quotes"';
str_replace ('“', '"', $str);

echo $str;

// Prints:
// “evil curly quotes“ no "good straight quotes"
?>
```

Please help me anyone, there has to be an easy way to do this besides manually editing thousands of records?

Comment: Are they stored as the curly quotes, or as the html code equiv? `&#147;`

Comment: @PhilCross Unfortunateley they are stored as the actual curly quotes, which are being used for HTML links which makes the links not work correctly

Comment: Unfortunately I cant help any further! Maybe this site will give you a clue? http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql

Comment: I don't think PHP changes the value of $str with what your doing. Try $str=str_replace(...)

Comment: @TomD you're right, good eye, thank you that does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually replacing any value. You forgot to assign the return value of the `str_replace` call to the `$str` variable. This will do the trick:

```
<?php
$str = ' “evil curly quotes“ no "good straight quotes"';
$str = str_replace ('“', '"', $str);

echo $str;

// Prints:
// “evil curly quotes“ no "good straight quotes"
?>
```

edit: Tom D also provided the correct answer in his comment (and did it earlier than me to be fair).

Comment: @TomD I have added a disclaimer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace smart or curly quotes, dashes and ellipses
// Replace UTF-8 characters.
$string = str_replace(
array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
$string);
// Replace Windows-1252 equivalents.
$string = str_replace(
array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
$string);
```