# PHP file is replacing first single quote ' with ‘

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, alpine.js

.php file is replacing the closing `'` with `‘` in output HTML.

```
<?php
 $foo = 'bar';
?>

<div x-data="{  
    foo: '<?php echo $foo ; ?>', 
    init(){
        console.log(this.foo)
        console.log('>')
    }   
}">
   <p x-text="foo"></p>
</div>
```

Page Source

```
<div x-data="{  
    foo: 'bar', 
    init(){
        console.log(this.foo)
        console.log('>&#8216;)
    }   
}&#8221;>
   <p x-text="foo"></p>
</div></div>
```

Inspector

```
<div x-data="{  
    foo: 'bar', 
    init(){
        console.log(this.foo)
        console.log('>‘)
    }   
}”>
   <p x-text=" foo"=""><p></p>
</div>
```

If I replace `>` with something else it works as expected

This is for a WordPress site using [Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/)/Twig & [ACF blocks](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/)

Editor: VS Code

### Narrowed it down

Tested in a local WordPress install and it seems to be an issue when rendering blocks through the [LazyBlock](https://lazyblocks.com/) or [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugins.

No issues if not within an Alpine JS component.

Comment: This is an OS, browser, or IDE issue, not a code issue. What are you using to write your code?

Comment: What did you already debug to determine that it's PHP and not something else? (code editor, some other apache module, etc)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please post codes not screenshot whenever possible. also, please add more context such as are those code in a `<? php` block or not. in regard to encoding as the others pointed out, you should see if your html is being treated as an utf-8 or something else. which can be set on either meta tags or http header.

Comment: Your final double-quote is also weird.

Comment: Curly quotes can display exactly like single and double quote characters in some fonts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479809/451969

Comment: Viewing the page source rather than inspector is usually more accurate. Please post PHP code.

Comment: Try deleting the bad quotes and retyping them?

Comment: Maybe its getting confused with >, try escaping it in console.log